# Understanding if opencv findHomography function takes care of Two View Geometry

Tags: opencv, geometry, homography, image-stitching

There are two cameras seaparated by some distance. My ultimate goal is to project points from both the cameras to one common plane( take points from camera 2 view plane to the camera 1 view plane) and then stitch together. Now if I want to transform a point in one camera view to the other camera view, can I use findHomography() opencv function to get the homography matrix even though the centre of projection of these twoplanes is different. I was checking [this document](http://file:///home/gayathri/Gadi/practise/cpp_test/cvpr03_part1.pdf) under the section Two View Geometry, if there are two projection views, we take an intermediat plane to find the final homgraphy. Please check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO7Ht.png) for reference.
As per my understanding the problem might occur if the intrinsic properties of the cameras are different, please correct me if I am wrong. In such a case as we only pass the matches set of points to the findHomography() function, how will that take care of this two view geometry. I am pretty confused understanding this. It would be really great if someone could explain this in detail. Will findHomography() in usecase give me correct Homography matrix ??

Comment: The first document is not accessible outside your computer. Do you want to achieve something similar to [perspective correction](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_Demo2)? Your ultimate goal should be in fact [panorama stitching](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/computational-photography-applications/image-composite-editor/), no?

Comment: not sure what exactly your scenario is, so i stay a bit general: Perspective homographies computed between 2d planes (like images) are correct only if the target scene is a plane, or if both image planes are captured from the same camera point. All this (and most other stereo geometry setups) assume pinhole cameras, so you would have to undistort your lenses/images etc. Typically you can work without filfilling the assumptions but you'll get increasing errors the more you differ from those assumptions. From your linked image I don't understand what you mean by the "intermediate plane"

Comment: In your linked image, plane X and X' look like the images (projection plane) while plane Pi is the captured scene. If your captured scene isn't a real plane, points C and C' must be equal (but the directions for X and X' may differ) for a homography to transform between X and X' perfectly without any errors.